# Swift CloudKit not working with Cellular (Time exceeded)

Tags: swift, cloudkit

I'm using following code to fetch Data from iCloud:

```
func fetchShoppingList() {

    let container = CKContainer.default()
    let publicDB = container.publicCloudDatabase
    let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)

    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "ShoppingList", predicate: predicate)

    let operation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
    operation.allowsCellularAccess = true
    operation.qualityOfService = .userInitiated

    publicDB.add(operation)

    publicDB.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil) { [unowned self] results, error in

        if error != nil {

            print(error)
        }
        else {

            for var value in results! {

                let shoppingListEntry = ShoppingListEntry()

                shoppingListEntry.index = value.value(forKey: "index") as! Int
                shoppingListEntry.product = value.value(forKey: "product") as! String
                shoppingListEntry.amount = value.value(forKey: "amount") as! Int
                shoppingListEntry.priority = value.value(forKey: "priority") as! Int

                if value.value(forKey: "isSelected") as! String == "true" {

                    shoppingListEntry.isSelected = true
                }
                else {

                    shoppingListEntry.isSelected = false
                }

                self.shoppingListEntrys.append(shoppingListEntry)
            }

            OperationQueue.main.addOperation({ () -> Void in
                self.tableViewShoppingList.reloadData()
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works fine if my phone is connected via Wifi, but if I'm using Cellular I get following error: CKError 0x170244e30: "Network Failure" (4/-1001); "Zeitüberschreitung bei der Anforderung." So there seems to be a problem with time exceeding. I looked for a solution and found a post, saying I have to add the operation lines but nothing changed.
Can anybody help me please?